# NSOperation queue problems

Tags: iphone, nsoperationqueue

hello i have 2 methods which are accessing on the same method redrawView those are moveThePlayerWithDeltasAndQueue
and 
movethePlayerAroundYAxisAndQueue
i would like to use an operation queue like in the commented code but i have no fortune to run it well what is the right way for build the queue and let work them right  ?

http://pastebin.com/DfS7p6FM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing to do was drawn on the back buffer i forgot it : (